How to make changes from ObservableObject derived class reflect into interface automatically?
I am using ObservableObject from CommunityToolkit in a WPF program. It looks like this:
It's like a ViewModel, I think:
public class MyParameters: ObservableObject
{
    // many other values are here
    public double ValAngleDegrees { get; set;}
}

A control looks like this:
<StackPanel x:Name="AnglePanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
   <TextBox Name="TxtAngleDeg" Width="100" Margin="2" Text="{Binding Path=ValAngleDegrees, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" KeyUp="TxtAngleDeg_KeyUp"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>

I initialize it like this:
public MyParameters renderValues { get; set; }
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    renderValues = new MyParameters { ValAngleDegrees = 0 };
    AnglePanel.DataContext = renderValues;
}

When I change value in textbox, value in ObservableObject is changed like expected, BUT THE PROBLEM IS - when I change value in code it does not get changed in UI. How do I solve this?

It is not required to call SetProperty manually in a property setter. Community Toolkit provides the ObservableProperty attribute, which automatically generates a property with change notification. See the other answer.

You need to call the SetProperty in the property setter. It will trigger the PropertyChanged from the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. The UI controls register on this event, so it get triggered to update the UI.
public class User : ObservableObject
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set => SetProperty(ref name, value);
    }
}

Source: ObservableObject

It is not necessary to do this explicitly. Just use the ObservableProperty attribute.

@Clemens nice addition, thanks

Not just an addition, but indeed the preferred way to declare such properties. It saves a lot of code.

You would use the ObservableProperty attribute to automatically generate properties with change notification, i.e. which fire the PropertyChanged event when their value is changed.
This will generate a property named ValAngleDegrees:
public partial class MyParameters : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private double valAngleDegrees;
}


@Ivan P. This is how you should use ObservableObject and ObservableProperty. The source generator will create a "ValAngleDegrees" property for you.
